# TCP to HTTP communication

Tags: java, http, tcp, iot, teltonika

I have an IOT device which is sending data continuously to a configured server using TCP protocol.

Can i receive the data using HTTP protocol and any java http services application like spring-boot application?

Device details : https://teltonika.lt/product/fmb920/

Comment: TCP e HTTP works on two differents layers of the network. HTTP is based on tcp/ip

Comment: Not unless IoT device sends data on HTTP - which it likely does not. You need to first figure out which protocol the device is using ( MQTT is popular for such devices so that might be it, in which case see https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/mqtt.html)

Comment: @nos the device is teltonika fmb920 which sends data using TCP/UDP protocol. added link in the question too...please have a look and guide me..thank you

Comment: @Alien TCP/UDP protocol is a transport protocol. On top of that there are many hundreds of different protocols that define what the data look like and what procedures must be taken to make communication work. It is not enough to just know that it is "a TCP protocol". e.g. HTTP is a protocol on top of TCP. Unfortunately none of the documents at your link gives any further description as to what protocol this particular device uses on top of TCP, so you have to do further investigation or contact the vendor and ask them for more documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the device was returning the data in TCP protocol so I could not get any solution to get data in http protocol.

I achieved that **by establishing the TCP connection using sockets.**